# Center div not working in IE8?

Tags: html, css, stylesheet, styling

Never had problems with centering divs before but I have been trying to get 100% height columns (which I have achieved for most browsers). I believe that the 100% height is messing with the centering of the div in IE8.

So basically I'm trying to get `#wholewrap` to center align and I'm currently using `margin: 0 auto;` but it doesn't work for IE8?

Any ideas why this bug occurs or how to fix it?

If you try this code it should work in FF, Chrome and Opera, havn't got IE9.

For some reason the results for this in JSFiddle vary for IE8 for some reason, what it shows in JSFiddle is not actually what it shows in IE8.

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="newcss.css"/>
</head>
<body>

<div id='wholewrap'>

    <div class='ttc'>
       <p>
          Left Column<br />
          Left Column<br />
          Left Column<br />
       </p>
    </div>

    <div class='otc'>
       <p>
          Right Column<br />
          Right Column<br />          
       </p>
    </div>

    <br style='clear:both;' />
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
div{border:1px #000 solid;}

html{height: 100%;}

body{height: 100%;}

#wholewrap{width:500px;margin:0 auto;min-height: 100%;height: 100%;}

.ttc{width:45%;float:left;min-height: 100%;height: 100%;}
.otc{width:45%;float:right;min-height: 100%;height: 100%;}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It could be related to the `doctype` .. try to put `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">` or HTML5 one `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` above your `<html>`

Comment: Spot on. Thanks for this. Works a treat

Comment: Breaks in olde browsers though.

Comment: Check your site at http://browsershots.org/ or an alike service and see for yourself. Describing each single "glitch" would be too much for this comment area; especially without the screenshots.

Comment: Sorry, what are you saying?? The problem **here** is the missing doctype and the answer is accepted and tested, wtf u -1 this answer???